# c++ expected type-specifier before '…' token exception

Tags: c++, exception

I have this code and it gives me this error:

> expected type-specifier before 'ToolongString' token.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "student.h";
#include <exception>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    student stud1;
    int a,b;
    string c,d;
    cout<<"Enter the First Name"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    try
    {
        stud1.setFirstName(c);
        cout<<"Family Name: "<<stud1.getFirstName()<<endl;
    }
    catch (ToolongString ex1)//error
    {
        cout<< ex1.ShowReason() <<endl;
    }
     return 0;
  }
```

and this is the TooLongString class:

```
class ToolongString{
public:

    char *ShowReason()
    {
        return "The name is too long";
    }

};
```

and I have a header file of the class student like this:

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

class student
{

 public:
    student();
    virtual ~student();
    int studentId,yearOfStudy;
    string firstName,familyName;

    void setFirstName(string name);
    void setFamilyName(string surname);
    void setStudentId(int id);
    void setYearOfStudy(int year);
    string getFirstName();
    string getFamilyName();
    int getStudentId();
    int getYearOfStudy();
    };
    #endif /
```

In the student.cpp file a I have other exceptions like that one.

Comment: You haven't shown us a complete source file, but I don't see a closing `}` for `main`.

Comment: Possibly the compiler doesn't know the class ToolongString at the point you are trying to catch it. You need a declaration of it before main, possibly in a header file.

Comment: The `ShowReason` function is illegal since C++11, it should return `char const *`

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for the bad information. Now i added all i have except the student.cpp file

Comment: @Javier Muhlach: The compiler has no idea what `ToolongString` is. Where is this class declared? In any case, it is clear that the compiler does not see the class declaration. Your "and this is the TooLongString class" is not helping much, since the compiler definitely won't look in your SO post for the declaration. Where is that declaration located? Which file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ToolongString{
public:

    char const *ShowReason()  // Changed return type to const
    {
        return "The name is too long";
    }

};

int main()
{
    string c;
    cout<<"Enter the First Name"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    try
    {
        if (c.length() > 10) throw(ToolongString()); // Max 10 chars allowed or it throws

        cout<<"Family Name: "<<c<<endl;  // Okay - print it
    }
    catch (ToolongString& ex1)   // Change to & (reference)
    {
        cout<< ex1.ShowReason() <<endl;
    }
}
```

Try it at ideone.com - http://ideone.com/e.js/uwWVA9

**EDIT**
due to comment

You can't just place the class `ToolongString` inside student.cpp. You must declare/define it in `student.h` so that the compiler knows it when compiling main. Put the class in student.h instead.

Each cpp file is compiled without knowing the contents of other cpp-files. Therefore you must to give the compiler all the information it needs to compile a cpp-file. That is done by declaring things (classes) in h-files and then include the h-files where relevant. The implementation can be kept in a cpp-file but you can also put the implementation (of classes) in the h-file if you like.

In your case you need (at least) to tell the compiler that you have a class named `ToolongString` and that the class has a function named `ShowReason`.

Comment: What did you change? How and why?

Comment: @JavierMuhlach - Do you have the class `ToolongString` declared before `main` ?

Comment: Before the main I dont have anything. The class ToolongString i have it declared in the student.cpp file

Comment: @JavierMuhlach - then you need to declare the class in student.h. When compiling `main` the compiler needs to know how `ToolongString ` looks. You can't just hide it inside a cpp-file.